# Non-root user login with key

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, login

I have the keys setup for the root user so I can login as root like so:

```
ssh -p xxxx root@xx.xx.xx.xx
```

but I want to login as a non-root user `john` that I have created and verified, also set its home dir. Additionally, I also modified `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to include:

```
AllowUsers john
```

.. but I still get:

```
~> ssh -p xxxx john@xx.xx.xx.xx
Permission denied (publickey).
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You should create `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` in the desired user's home folder too. Even better, use `ssh-copy-id`.

Comment: I think you can make `ssh-copy-id` to login as root and add keys to different user with `-o` option.

Comment: `ssh-copy-id -o User=root john@1.2.3.4`

Comment: You should include that in the answer.